# Resize image with limit in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to resize image in linux and want this image to be convert to below the threshold value (certain limit).

eg. Threshold Limit: 500Kb, Image dimension: 100x100

Output image will be in 100x100 dimension and size below 500Kb or exactly 500kb (Not more than 500Kb)

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) inside a shell script and do the following:

1. Scale down your image to 100x100 pixels.
2. Check if the files size is <= 500kb
3. If yes: youre done.
4. If not: user imagemagicks "convert" to convert your image to a lower quality and then go back to step 2.